# Trouble with scraping links with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, href

Here's my script :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

url0 = 'https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/opcvm/'

results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

n=2
m = 2

linklist = []

while n <= m:
      # Source path
      url = f"https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/opcvm/page-{n}?sortAsc=1"
      results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

      links = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "o-pack__item u-ellipsis", attrs={"href"})

      for i in links:
        print(i.get('href'))

      n = n+1
```

I obtained this :

```
None
None
None
None
None
```

I don't understand why, when I run this (I just changed a line of code : `print(i)` :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

url0 = 'https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/opcvm/'

results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

n=2
m = 3

linklist = []

while n <= m:
      # Source path
      url = f"https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/opcvm/page-{n}?sortAsc=1"
      results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

      links = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "o-pack__item u-ellipsis", attrs={"href"})

      for i in links:
        print(i)

      n = n+1
```

I obtained this :

```
<div class="o-pack__item u-ellipsis"><a class="c-link c-link--animated" href="/bourse/opcvm/cours/0P0001CBIB/" title="Allianz Global Government Bond W H EUR">Allianz Global Government Bond W H EUR</a></div>
<div class="o-pack__item u-ellipsis"><a class="c-link c-link--animated" href="/bourse/opcvm/cours/0P0001HEV7/" title="Allianz Global Credit SRI WT Hedged SEK">Allianz Global Credit SRI WT Hedged SEK</a></div>
<div class="o-pack__item u-ellipsis"><a class="c-link c-link--animated" href="/bourse/opcvm/cours/0P0001AM5S/" title="Barings Global High Yield Bond C AUD Acc">Barings Global High Yield Bond C AUD Acc</a></div>
<div class="o-pack__item u-ellipsis"><a class="c-link c-link--animated" href="/bourse/opcvm/cours/0P00012TCF/" title="GS NA Engy &amp; Engy Infras Eq Base Inc USD">GS NA Engy &amp; Engy Infras Eq Base Inc USD</a></div>
<div class="o-pack__item u-ellipsis"><a class="c-link c-link--animated" href="/bourse/opcvm/cours/0P0001ESKF/" title="DWS Invest Enh Cmdty Strat USD TFC">DWS Invest Enh Cmdty Strat USD TFC</a></div>
```

We can see the `href` tag, I searched on internet but I always see `i.get('href')` or `i['href']` and it always end up with `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What happens?

You are selecting a `<div>` and these do not have an attribute `href`, the `<a>` is enclosed by the `<div>`

```
<div class="o-pack__item u-ellipsis"><a class="c-link c-link--animated" href="/bourse/opcvm/cours/0P0001CBIB/" title="Allianz Global Government Bond W H EUR">Allianz Global Government Bond W H EUR</a></div>
```

#### How to fix

If you like to print the value of the `href`, you have to select it first:

```
print(i.a.get('href'))
```

An alternativ would be to select your targets more specific e.g. with `css selectors`:

```
links = soup.select('div.o-pack__item.u-ellipsis a[href]')

for i in links:
    print(i.get('href'))
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.espncricinfo.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
}

url0 = 'https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/opcvm/'

results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

n=2
m = 2

linklist = []

while n <= m:
      # Source path
    url = f"https://www.boursorama.com/bourse/opcvm/page-{n}?sortAsc=1"
    results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    links = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "o-pack__item u-ellipsis", attrs={"href"})

    for i in links:
        print(i.a.get('href'))

    n = n+1
```

Comment: It worked ! Thank you sir :) I knew it was something with the path. i tried with  `a` but I did it wrong. Upvoted and approved !